# Google Apps Script using doGet() entry point after a POST request

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-apps-script, expo

I have a simple function which makes a post request to the development version of a Google Appscript web application. When making the fetch request it gives me this error in the console of my Expo web app.

> Access to fetch at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/~MyScriptID~/exec' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Following the link to the google script presents me with a page that says this

```
Script function not found: doGet
```

I don't think the cors policy is the cause of the issue since I've had a google appscript web application working in the past and the console would present me with the same cors block error whenever I made an error in google appscript.

Here is my post request,

```js
const res = await fetch(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SHEETSURL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'firstname': firstname,
      'lastname': lastname,
    })
    
  })
  
  const output = await res.text()
  console.log(output)
```

And here is my entire google apps script, it shouldn't do anything with the event that gets passed in

```js
function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello World!")
}
```

Comment: [Bug Report](- [Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905))

Comment: Can I ask you about the setting of your Web Apps? What are the values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? And, in your situation, the account of your Web Apps is in Google Workspace? Can I ask you about the detailed method for replicating `Following the link to the google script presents me with a page that says this` and `Script function not found: doGet`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Sure, the values are `Execute as: Me (email)` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone` I'm new to stack overflow so forgive me if this replication method is insufficient. **replicate:**  _I would execute the above post request in a jsfiddle or something similar and replace the environmental variable with the url of a deployed google appscript web app with only the doPost(e) function given above._ I tried this method in jsfiddle myself and the console also gave me the cors policy error. I clicked on the first https link and that led me to the error page in the second block quote.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your reply, I understood that your setting of Web Apps is as follows.

- `Execute as: Me`
- `Who has access to the app: Anyone`

In this case, it is not required to use the access token. But, when I saw your script, I thought that `"Content-Type": "application/json",` is not required to be used. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/a72aab0242012362c46ec69031c720d5) So, please test the following modified script.

#### Modified script:

```js
const res = await fetch(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SHEETSURL, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'firstname': firstname,
    'lastname': lastname,
  })
});
const output = await res.text();
console.log(output);
```

When I tested this modified script, I confirmed that `Hello World!` is shown in the console.

Comment: Thank you that worked great! I didn't think the header would've caused the error I was having. I would give you a rep but I don't meet the requirements yet.

Comment: As a side note, using the web app url from Test Deployment also causes the same cors policy console error and  error page in the original post, whereas the manual deployment url does not. Do you know what might be causing this? I have not changed any of the settings

Comment: @Brian Buslon About `Thank you that worked great!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Brian Buslon About your 2nd question of `As a side note, using the web app url from Test Deployment also causes the same cors policy console error and error page in the original post, whereas the manual deployment url does not. Do you know what might be causing this? I have not changed any of the settings`, I cannot understand your `Test Deployment`. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you on that; I have hit the accept button. For the details of test deployment: I used the same modified script you gave in your answer except `I replaced process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SHEETSURL with the web app url given under Deploy > Test Deployments > Web App` In Google App Script. The Settings are still `Execute as: Me` and `Who Has Access: Anyone`

Comment: @Brian Buslon Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood about `Test Deployment`. In that case, when you access the Web Apps with `Test Deployment`, it is required to access using the access token. This is the current specification. Also, when you want to make other users access your Web Apps with `Test Deployment`, it is required to share the Google Apps Script project with the users. Please be careful about this.